# Ruby on Rails - Run after_save only if new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, updates, before-save, after-save

In my application I have models `Post` & `Image`. My association are:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: :image_rejectable?, allow_destroy: true

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
```

*I use `cocoon gem` for `nested_forms`*

When user is adding images, I have some **global settings** that user can apply to images they are adding.

*I do it by doing:*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: :image_rejectable?, allow_destroy: true

  after_create :global_settings

  private

    def global_settings
      self.images.each { |image| image.update_attributes(
                            to_what: self.to_what,
                            added_to: self.added_to,
                            )
                      }
    end
```

This works fine, but now I want it so if they want to `edit` `post's images`, I want to apply same **post global settings** **ONLY** to **new records**.

*I tried to do it by doing:*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: :image_rejectable?, allow_destroy: true

  after_save :global_settings

  private

  def global_settings
    if new_record?
      self.images.each { |image| image.update_attributes(
          to_what: self.to_what,
          added_to: self.added_to,
      )
      }
    end
  end
```

This didn't worked at all & **global setting** were not added to any record *(nor on `new/create` or `edit/update` action)*.

*I've also tried with:*

```
after_save :global_settings, if: new_record?
```

This gave me error: `undefined method 'new_record?' for Post`

How can I only apply my **global** settings for all **new records/new images**?

*ps: I tried to find some answer on SO, but nothing worked!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `images` doesn't have those *global settings* means that you can only execute the `function` only on `images` that doesn't have all `fields`.

```
def global_settings
  self.images.each { |image|
    if image.to_what.blank?
      image.update_attributes(
          to_what: self.to_what,
          added_to: self.added_to
      )
    end
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```
def global_settings
# if new_record? # Change this to
  if self.new_record?
  self.images.each { |image| image.update_attributes(
      to_what: self.to_what,
      added_to: self.added_to,
  )
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikram. Yeah that could work, if only wanted to apply it only when `post` is new, but in my case I also want to apply global settings when `post` is not new but images added are new.

Comment: In that case just add the same code to the image mode. the code to apply global settings should be in image.rb
What say?